# Listing multiple values from the same record multiple times in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a PDF "student record" that we need to print the values on. Because of this, all values must be printed where they are listed on the pdf and I can't just put everything in a list format. I have attached a screenshot of the bottom lefthand corner of the PDF as an example.

[image: PDF]

Obviously, grouping wouldn't allow me to print out different values of the same record like this. It probably wouldn't allow me top specify which record goes on which line exactly either.

Is it possible to make a formula field that pulls the correct record for each line?

For example, dragging the "Student.Relationship.FirstName" field always lists whatever 'first' relationship is on their record.
Can I make a formula that specifies that will pull the second relationship record instead of defaulting to the first?

Can I make a formula that can specify "student.relationship.firstname" WHERE student.relationship.type = "father"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBREPORTS..` I think that is what you need. Create a grouping on STUDENT, add Extra sections for the same group and on each section insert a different Subreport that has details as required.
Pass the Student ID as the sub-report link.